# How can I stop my JavaScript from giving the <nav> element the "is-selected" class name too

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I select each colour tab, the image changes colour.  However, when you miss the tab or select just off the colour tab or any other part of the “nav” container for the “a” element it adds the is-select class to this also; meaning there is no image.  Very frustrated, and would like some help please as to how I can stop the “nav” element being given the is-select classname, as I just need the “a” elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-pane__swatch-container"> 
  <div class="tab-pane__swatch-content"> 
    <div class="tab-pane is-selected" id="red">
      <img src="https://www.bristolstreetversa.com/images/colour_swatches/Grand-Tourneo-Connect/Red.png" alt="Red Versa" class="tab-pane__swatch-image">
    </div>              
    <div class="tab-pane" id="black">
      <img src="https://www.bristolstreetversa.com/images/colour_swatches/Grand-Tourneo-Connect/Black.png" alt="Red Versa" class="tab-pane__swatch-image">
    </div>                          
  </div>

  <nav class="row-1 tab-pane__swatch-selector" id="js-swatch">
    <a href="#red" class="tab-pane__swatch-link tab-pane__swatch-link--red is-selected"></a>
    <a href="#black" class="tab-pane__swatch-link tab-pane__swatch-link--black"></a>
  </nav>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-pane__swatch-image {
  width: 90%;
}

.row-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 10px #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link--red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link--black {
  background: #000;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-pane.is-selected {
  display: table;
}

a.is-selected::before {
  content: '';
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: initial;
  margin: 8px 0 0 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 1rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
}
```

**JS**

```
function onSwatchClick(event) {
  let selectedSwatches = document.querySelectorAll('.is-selected');                   

  for(let i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {                            
    selectedSwatches[i].className = selectedSwatches[i].className.replace('is-selected', '');
  }

  event.preventDefault();   
  event.target.className += ' is-selected'; 
  document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).className += ' is-selected'; 
}

const elswatchClick = document.getElementById('js-swatch');                        
elswatchClick.addEventListener('click', onSwatchClick, false);
```

Hope you can help thank you.

Comment: You can check to see if `event.target.matches("a")` in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ryan's answer is much cleaner than this.

You could make sure that the element that was actually clicked was an "A" tag. Here's how you could do that:

```
if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
    // An <a> tag was clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler is targeting the tab parent element, not the individual tab triggers. As such, it's not updating the element classes correctly.

Instead, I targeted the class of `tab-pane__swatch-link` and looped through them, attaching the event listener to each one.

```js
function onSwatchClick(event) {
  let selectedSwatches = document.querySelectorAll('.is-selected');                   

  for(let i = 0; i < selectedSwatches.length; i++) {                            
    selectedSwatches[i].className = selectedSwatches[i].className.replace('is-selected', '');
  }

  event.preventDefault();   
  event.target.className += ' is-selected'; 
  document.getElementById(event.target.href.split('#')[1]).className += ' is-selected'; 
}

const elswatchClick = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane__swatch-link');                        
for (var i = 0; i < elswatchClick.length; i++) {
  elswatchClick[i].addEventListener('click', onSwatchClick, false);
}
```

```css
.tab-pane__swatch-image {
  width: 90%;
}

.row-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 10px #a9a9a9;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link--red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.tab-pane__swatch-link--black {
  background: #000;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-pane.is-selected {
  display: table;
}

a.is-selected::before {
  content: '';
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  display: initial;
  margin: 8px 0 0 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 1rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane__swatch-container"> 
  <div class="tab-pane__swatch-content"> 
    <div class="tab-pane is-selected" id="red">
      <img src="https://www.bristolstreetversa.com/images/colour_swatches/Grand-Tourneo-Connect/Red.png" alt="Red Versa" class="tab-pane__swatch-image">
    </div>              
    <div class="tab-pane" id="black">
      <img src="https://www.bristolstreetversa.com/images/colour_swatches/Grand-Tourneo-Connect/Black.png" alt="Red Versa" class="tab-pane__swatch-image">
    </div>                          
  </div>

  <nav class="row-1 tab-pane__swatch-selector" id="js-swatch">
    <a href="#red" class="tab-pane__swatch-link tab-pane__swatch-link--red is-selected"></a>
    <a href="#black" class="tab-pane__swatch-link tab-pane__swatch-link--black"></a>
  </nav>  
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, nice and clean too.  Thank you Ryan.